# ER:Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

vui lòng: Đã tìm kiếm nhưng không tìm thấy giải pháp ... Tại sao nó không hoạt động? có gì sai với móc ở đây?
tại vị trí :....

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
    import {createStore} from 'redux';
    import myReducer from './components/trainning/reducer/index';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

    const store = createStore(myReducer);
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
         </Provider>,
            
         document.getElementById('root')
    );
    registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: English translation for the Vietnamese (via Google Translate): "please: Searched but didn't find a solution... Why doesn't it work? What's wrong with the hook here? at position :".

Comment: From the code you have provided I can see no improper use of hooks. This probably means that the issue is deeper in your component tree and we would need to see more code to be able to help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because all questions on SO must be asked in english